# Input range fires "input" event on mouseup in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

It seems like using the `input` event on a `type=range` input element works differently in Webkit and Firefox. I really don't understand why the event fires both on sliding the slider **and** while releasing the mouse.

I very much do **not** want the event to fire again when releasing the mouse button.

Any ideas how to stop this `mouseup` nonsense with the input event?

```js
var counter = document.querySelector('div'),
    rangeInput = document.querySelector('input');

rangeInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
  counter.innerHTML = 1 + +counter.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
body{ font:18px Arial; }
input{ width:80%; }
div{ color:red; }
div::before{ content:'Event fired: '; color:#555; }
div::after{ content:' times'; color:#555; }
```

```html
<p>Try to click the slider, wait and release the mouse</p>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1">

<div>0</div>
```

[Demo page](http://jsbin.com/galijekovi/edit?html,css,js,output)

---

### Update: opened a [bug in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287321)

Comment: In which browser does the problematic `mouseup` event fire? Having tried it in Chrome (51.x, Windows 10) it doesn't seem to be firing, but I don't want to assume that it's Firefox demonstrating the problem.

Comment: problem seems to be on firefox

Comment: @DavidThomas - the same browser which is mentioned in the title

Answer (score 1):

How about listening to the `change` event instead of `input`?

As per your example:

```js
var counter = document.querySelector('div'),
    rangeInput = document.querySelector('input');

rangeInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
  counter.innerHTML = 1 + +counter.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
body{ font:18px Arial; }
input{ width:80%; }
div{ color:red; }
div::before{ content:'Event fired: '; color:#555; }
div::after{ content:' times'; color:#555; }
```

```html
<p>Try to click the slider, wait and release the mouse</p>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1">

<div>0</div>
```

This seems to be a browser bug nevertheless. [See this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/554) posted in react project.

What you could do is to have this as a fallback in browsers that show this behaviour. Detect the browsers that are doing this and have this fallback for them which cancels out the extra increament.

```js
var counter = document.querySelector('div'),
    rangeInput = document.querySelector('input');

rangeInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
  counter.innerHTML = 1 + +counter.innerHTML;
});
 rangeInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
  /* if firefox - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/1437261 */
  if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'){
     counter.innerHTML =  counter.innerHTML - 1;
  }
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
body{ font:18px Arial; }
input{ width:80%; }
div{ color:red; }
div::before{ content:'Event fired: '; color:#555; }
div::after{ content:' times'; color:#555; }
```

```html
<p>Try to click the slider, wait and release the mouse</p>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1">

<div>0</div>
```

Comment: @dandavis well depends on how he wants it.

Comment: This is not a solution.. **(a)** I do not want `change` event **(b)** obviously the I made a demo showing the bug but in reality i don't count anything but perform code which much more complexity which shouldn't be fired **at all** on `mouseup`

Comment: @vsync obviously it is a bug ( or, i would call it a dissimilarity between the engines). I guess it will be patched sooner or later. All I focused to do here is to have a temporary solution before that. more complex code will need more complex solution. I would gladly solve it if I could, if you post the problem :)

Comment: I am afraid the real code is so complex it is un-postable, because the event triggers events of other components which themselves use even larger components and libraries. I've updated my answer with the reported bug in bugzilla. you could help by starring it :)